# aspnet core RC2 When does the User (claimsprincipal) get initialized

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In the controller classes you have access to the User, which is just a claimsprincipal.  (see below)

[image]

At what point does this get initialized?  And how, by what method?  Could I do this manually?

The reason I ask is because I want to be able to get the user upon logging in, but because they have not yet logged in the User is null.  But I want to be able to access the users claims in the login action.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out thanks anyways guys.[image]